# Injective map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into the coordinate axes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ and $X := \mathbb{R} × \{0\} ∪ \{0\} × \mathbb{R}$ are equipotent using the Cantor-Bernstein theorem and the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are. Since we clearly have the injection $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, we only need one the other way around. I seem to remember there was a clever trick for this, but I can't reproduce it. Does anyone remember it?

Comment: Using CB + the fact that $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are equipotent is overkill. $X$ is clearly equipotent to $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty).$

Comment: It's in the exercise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have
$$
\Bbb R\hookrightarrow X\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^2\hookrightarrow \Bbb R
$$